# Making smallest entry of each column bold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting, format

I've just finished running some code and combined it into the following table:

```
# Write to DataFrame

Results_test = pd.DataFrame({'MAE': Results_MAE_test,
                        'MinE': Results_MinE_test, 
                        'MaxE': Results_MaxE_test,
                        'MSE':Results_MSE_test},
                        index={'OLS','DeepNN'})
```

How can I write a function which returns the same table but with the smallest value of each column made bold?  (any the largest made italic)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df.style.apply(lambda col: ['font-weight:bold' if x==col.min() else '' for x in col])
```

Output:

[image]

Can you tweak it to get italic at maximal values?

Comment: Nice one `font-family:'italic'` i guess for italic with same logic for max. TIL :-)

Comment: Oh my...you made my day! :3  Genius!